# How to give data in small parts from BE to the FE?

Tags: node.js, http, stream, hapi

My case is that, web application (FE / react.js) is trying to generate a csv file with the response coming from the gateway (BE / node.js) service request.

Because the data is too large, FE is sending partial requests with using limit and offset values. And then it tries to merge it.

But FE wants to get the data in a single request. For this problem, looks like we can use stream. However, when i searched for its usage, I couldn't find an example.

On gateway service, how can I send multiple requests to internal service using limit and offset, and serve it to FE via stream?

I'm expecting to return the data by parts to the web application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Stream or Server-Sent Events (SSE) is the way to go. In your case, I recommend trying SSE.

Here are some examples to start:

https://dev.to/dhiwise/how-to-implement-server-sent-events-in-nodejs-11d9

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-server-sent-events-build-realtime-app